# Android fragment lifecycle added more items into List on pressing back button

Tags: android, android-fragments

As i'm using [FragNav](https://github.com/ncapdevi/FragNav) library i have some items into `List` and when i switching on other fragment and after pressing on `BackButton` i have some other items into this List,

for example generally i have 1 item into `List` with `RecyclerView` after switching on other fragment and pressing back button on phone i have 2 items into `RecyclerView` and using `onSaveInstanceState`, 
`onActivityCreated` couldn't resolve my problem

my Fragment:

```
public class HomeFragment extends BaseFragment implements IAnimationListener, View.OnClickListener, InstagramFeedsAdapter.OnClickListener {

    ...
    // constructor
    public static HomeFragment createInstance(int instance) {
        HomeFragment fragment = new HomeFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(BaseFragment.ARGS_INSTANCE, instance);
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.instagram_post_container, container, false);

        activity = getActivity();
        context = getActivity().getBaseContext();

        mediaUrls = new ArrayList<>();
        feedsSchema = new FeedsSchema();
        feedsSchema.setId(1);
        mediaUrls.add("http://gizasystems.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/natural-world-hero3.jpg");
        feedsSchema.setFeed_media_url(mediaUrls);
        feedsSchema.setFollowers_count(10);
        feedsSchema.setFollowings_count(20);
        feedsSchema.setPage_name("my test");
        feedsSchema.setType(FeedsSchema.feed_types.IMAGE);
        items.add(feedsSchema);

        instagram_feeds = mView.findViewById(R.id.instagram_feeds);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        instagram_feeds.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        instagram_feeds.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);

        instagramFeedsAdapter = new InstagramFeedsAdapter(activity, context, this, items);

        return mView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Bundle arguments = getArguments();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        int clickedItem = view.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, String transitionName, int position) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelableArrayList("someVarA", new ArrayList<>(items));
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (savedInstanceState != null)
            items = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList("someVarA");
    }
}
```

and my Adapter:

```
public class InstagramFeedsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<InstagramFeedsAdapter.InstagramFeedsViewHolder>
        implements PreviewView.OnPreviewChangeListener {

    private OnClickListener listener;
    private List<FeedsSchema> feedsItems;
    private Context context;
    private boolean hoveredOnPopup = false;
    private ExoPlayerManager exoPlayerManager;
    private Activity activity;

    private enum feedType {
        IMAGE,
        IMAGESLIDER,
        VIDEO
    }

    public InstagramFeedsAdapter(Activity activity, Context context, OnClickListener listener, List<FeedsSchema> items) {
        this.listener = listener;
        this.feedsItems = items;
        this.context = context;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final InstagramFeedsViewHolder holder, int position) {
        int feedType = feedsItems.get(position).getType().ordinal();
        implementingGeneralViewData(holder, position);
        if (feedType == 0) {
            if (feedsItems.get(position).getFeed_media_url().size() > 1) {
                implementingImageSliderView(holder, position);
            } else {
                implementingImageView(holder, position);
            }
        } else {
            implementingVideoPlayerView(holder, position);
        }
    }

    private void implementingVideoPlayerView(InstagramFeedsViewHolder holder, int position) {
    }

    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    private void implementingImageSliderView(final InstagramFeedsViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    }

    @SuppressLint("CheckResult")
    private void implementingImageView(final InstagramFeedsViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return feedsItems.size();
    }

    public class InstagramFeedsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
            implements View.OnClickListener, PopupInflaterListener, PopupStateListener, PopupOnHoverListener {
        ...

        public InstagramFeedsViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }

        public void bind(int position) {
            ...
        }

}
```

Comment: If `onActivityCreated()` is executed first and `onCreateView()` afterwards, you would first retrieve all the data from the *savedInstanceState* and somehow add them to *items* (which may be some kind of List?) and then add some more from *feedSchema* . You can check if I'm guessing correctly by writing something to Logcat in the two methods.

Comment: @0X0nosugar your mean is i must move retrieving data to `onActivityCreated()`?

Comment: I don't know your exact workflow but maybe it's sufficient to call clear() on the List to get rid of obsolete items before adding the new batch of items?